# below cell getting moved to right on cell swipe delete in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

The pink color is given to the content view of the cell.

[image]

While deleting cell by swipe delete using delegate `commitEditingStyle`

[image]

After deleting the cell just below the deleted cell gets moved to right

I am getting no idea about that left margin for the cell.
While scrolling and returning to that misplaced cell, the layout gets correct and that margin get removed.

I am using Swift in Xcode 8.0.

Here is the code :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {
            // handle delete (by removing the data from your array and updating the tableview)
            let date = dateKeys[indexPath.section]
            var notificationObject = dataSection[date] as! [Notification]
            let deleteNotificationId = notificationObject[indexPath.row].notifId

            for notifObject in self.notificationArray {
                if notifObject.notifId == deleteNotificationId {
                    if let index = self.notificationArray.indexOf(notifObject) {
                        self.notificationArray.removeAtIndex(index)
                        self.dataSection = self.categorizeNotification(self.notificationArray)
                        self.dateKeys = self.sortArrayDate()
                        self.notificationTable.reloadData()
                        break
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am reloading the table after removing the item in the array in "commitEditingStyle" function.

Comment: post your commitEditingStyle code here.

Comment: mention code with screen shot here .

Comment: You should show your critical code here, without that it's too difficult to trace problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should write this code for delete row in table view:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    // the cells you would like the actions to appear needs to be editable
    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    if editingStyle == .delete
    {
        showsArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes , its already there in my code. The deletion is working by removing from the array and while reloading the data populating from the array is correct but the cell just below the deleted cell get moved to right.
Then after scrolling the table , and when that cell appears again, it get fixed in correct position.

Comment: Don't reload your table . Just remove object from array.

Answer (score 0):

Occour same problem.

```
   override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        if self.editingStyle != .delete && self.frame.origin.x > 0{
            var originFrame = self.frame
            originFrame.origin.x = 0
            self.frame = originFrame
        }
    }
```

Set the UITableViewCell `frame.origin.x` to zero avoid it.